# Monitor Track Xhr Network Request Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to show a JavaScript alert whenever there is a xhr network request, i want to monitor/track the requests for a specified url web.com/api/refresh
I don't want to open or send. Like there's a xhr network request every one minute, so i want to show alert every one minute, not only on page load.